# ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask_imgrate

Tags: python, flask

I follow the instruction on https://github.com/dternyak/React-Redux-Flask

I want to download the required flask modules:

```
$ sudo pip install flask flask_script flask_migrate flask_bcrypt 

[root: ~]$ sudo pip install flask_script flask_imgrate flask_bcrypt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Requirement already satisfied: flask_script in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (2.0.6)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask_imgrate (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask_imgrate
```

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using this command fix the problem.

```
pip install Flask-Migrate==2.6.0
```